# How to remove square brackets from viewdata value using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a ViewData to get a value from linq query, but the value returning is within a Square brackets and I need to get only the value inside the brackets. My code is below:

```
 var checkevents = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["EventsList"]))');
```

> Output returned : [2]

How do I get the  2 from the square brackets using jquery expected output that I want 2

Comment: The JSON being parsed is an array? Access the array element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The `[2]` represent an Array with a single value of `2`. You can call `checkevents[0]` to get the first element of the Array.